# Excluding two collections from one another in SCCM

Tags: sccm

What happens to members when you exclude two collections from one another in SCCM?

Scenario:

1. Collection A contains Machine A and excludes Collection B from membership.
2. Collection B contains nothing and excludes Collection A from membership.
3. Machine A gets added to Collection B

Possible outcomes:

- Machine A receives no deployments from either collection
- Machine A receives only deployments assigned to Collection A because SCCM doesn't know how to handle this weird nested membership.
- Machine A receives deployments assigned to both Collection A and Collection B because it is in both despite the exclude.
- Machine A bounces between collections as each is evaluated because SCCM doesn't explicitly handle this case, and one collection's membership is evaluated on a different schedule than the other.

Has anyone attempted this before? My goal would be for no deployments to be evaluated if an object has been added to both collections.

Comment: Never tried it, but your goal is what should happen, everything else would be a bug

Answer (score 0):

You're correct; you shouldn't get any deployments with that setup.